# How to register a click on every instance of a div class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is extremely simple.  When I click on any instance of a class, create a new element of that class.  The problem I'm running into is even though the click of the first instance is registered, and a new element is created.  Clicking the newly created element with that class name does not create another element.  I have to always click the first element in order for the script to work.

```
#html

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group" id="images_upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="text" class="text" placeholder="type in a description">
  </div>
</div>


#js

$(".file").click(function () {
  var image = document.getElementById("images_upload");
  var newInput = document.createElement("input");
  
  newInput.type = "file";
  newInput.name = "file";
  $(newInput).addClass("file");
  image.appendChild(newInput);
  $();
});
```

see my codepen

https://codepen.io/benjermann/pen/vYgyapb?editors=1111

Comment: getElementById is for a unique element that matches that ID. A new class is designed to be an array of class elements. That means you would need to parse a list of elements with that class name to find your element, perhaps by the element ID, or some other unique property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the element was added after the click function was bound.

Change it to the following and it should work.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".file", function() {
    var image = document.getElementById("images_upload");
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "file";
    newInput.name = "file";
    $(newInput).addClass("file");
    image.appendChild(newInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group" id="images_upload">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="text" class="text" placeholder="type in a description">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for, thank you